# Glib string utility functions (echivalent for strcspn)

Tags: glib

I want to extract string that exist after first occurrence of "/"

For example a have a char *card in one of this form:

```
    hw:0/Line

    default/Master
```

and I need char *channel (Line, Master, ...)

In standard C can use "strcspn" and "strlen"

```
    char *card, *channel;
    int i;

    i = strcspn(card, "/");
    if (i == strlen(card)) {
        channel = "Master";
    } else {
        card[i] = 0;
        channel = card + i + 1;
    }
```

How can I do this using glib string utility functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with `strcspn` and `strlen`?

GLib reimplements a lot of stuff C99 and POSIX because it targets C89 compilers.  It doesn't reimplement things like `strlen` or `strcspn` because there is no need to—they are in C89.

GLib also tends to implement UTF-8 versions of a lot of functions, and while there is a `g_utf8_strlen` I'm not aware of a `g_utf8_strcspn` I don't think it's really necessary in this case.  If it is then you'll probably have to implement it yourself by iterating through the string with `g_utf8_next_char` and checking against the result of `g_utf8_get_char` or `g_utf8_get_char_validated`.